# CMD - check folder path for a regular expression

Tags: cmd

I am searching for all the folders path that has a certain pattern.

```
Ex. 
D:\Testfolder>tree
Folder PATH listing for volume Working
D:.

├───fifth
│   ├───first
│   ├───second
│   └───third
│       └───_dn
│           ├───first
│           └───second
├───first
│   ├───first
│   └───second
│       └───_dn
│           ├───first
│           └───second
├───fourth
│   └───first
│       └───_dn
│           ├───first
│           └───second
├───second
│   ├───first
│   ├───second
│   └───third
│       └───_dn
│           └───first
└───third
    ├───first
    └───second
        └───_dn
            ├───first
            └───second
```

If the path has the word "_dn" then I need to save it in a file.

Expected Output:

```
D:\Testfolder\fifth\third\_dn
D:\Testfolder\fifth\third\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\fifth\third\_dn\second
D:\Testfolder\first\second\_dn
D:\Testfolder\first\second\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\first\second\_dn\second
D:\Testfolder\fourth\first\_dn
D:\Testfolder\fourth\first\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\fourth\first\_dn\second
D:\Testfolder\second\third\_dn
D:\Testfolder\second\third\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\third\second\_dn
D:\Testfolder\third\second\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\third\second\_dn\second
```

**Update 1**

Someone posted a almost correct answer and then deleted it. I could not track his name to refer him.

The code is

```
(For /R "D:\Testfolder" /D %A In (*_dn*) Do @Echo %A)>"savefile.txt"
```

The return value is

```
D:\Testfolder\fifth\third\_dn
D:\Testfolder\first\second\_dn
D:\Testfolder\fourth\first\_dn
D:\Testfolder\second\third\_dn
D:\Testfolder\third\second\_dn
```

However this return value is missing all the paths that has something after _dn\,

```
Ex.
D:\Testfolder\fifth\third\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\fifth\third\_dn\second
D:\Testfolder\first\second\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\first\second\_dn\second
D:\Testfolder\fourth\first\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\fourth\first\_dn\second
D:\Testfolder\second\third\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\third\second\_dn\first
D:\Testfolder\third\second\_dn\second
```

Comment: did you write the first line of code  `@echo off` in a script?

Comment: @muneeb_ahmed I actually wrote the code directly in CMD

Comment: Try using the command [Where /?](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) to locate and display files in a directory tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps try using `Dir` with `Find` like this:

```dos
(Dir /B/S/AD "D:\Testfolder"|Find /I "\_dn\")>"savefile.txt"
```

Comment: @blueray, I have edited my answer, sorry for the very poor example code!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('Dir /ad /s /b D:\Testfolder\ ^| find /I "_dn"') do @echo %a
```

Comment: "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

Comment: I think this code search for files. But I am looking for directory path.

Comment: @blueray ah ok so `_dn` is a folder !  this why dosen't match !

Comment: A little edit "do @echo %a" instead of "do echo %a "

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have an answer. If you wanted to take a step into PowerShell, you could do something like this. Someday, this will probably be considered more maintainable.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Filter '_dn' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } >savefile.txt
```

Or, using aliases and minimal parameters it could be cryptic and unmaintainable.

```
gci -di -rec -filt '_dn' -ea si | % { $_.FullName } >savefile.txt
```